# Accessing objects on multidimensional arrays with datatable

Tags: arrays, json, symfony, multidimensional-array, datatable

I have this json file with an array with 4 more arrays and one of them is an object:

```
[
  [
    {
      "codigo": "1",
      "razao": "Dicon Contabilidade Ltda",
      "registro": "50.016.823/0001-83",
      "fiscal": null,
      "contabil": null,
      "dp": null
    },
    {
      "codigo": "2",
      "razao": "B Rosa Nunes",
      "registro": "65.996.787/0001-39",
      "fiscal": null,
      "contabil": null,
      "dp": null
    },
    {
      "codigo": "3",
      "razao": "M & R Comercio De Pneus Ltda",
      "registro": "16.982.372/0001-09",
      "fiscal": null,
      "contabil": null,
      "dp": null
    },
    {
      "codigo": "4",
      "razao": "Dicon Administracao Ltda",
      "registro": "05.503.601/0001-30",
      "fiscal": null,
      "contabil": null,
      "dp": null
    },
    {
      "codigo": "5",
      "razao": "T H R Marcelino Conveniencia E Lanchonete",
      "registro": "08.902.847/0001-73",
      "fiscal": null,
      "contabil": null,
      "dp": null
    },
    {
      "codigo": "6",
      "razao": "Manuel Bernardo Da Silva Neto",
      "registro": "05.962.291/0001-12",
      "fiscal": "Aline",
      "contabil": "Augusto",
      "dp": "Rosilene"
    }
  ],
  [
    "Adriele",
    "Aline",
    "Bruna",
    "Mariana",
    "Celso"
  ],
  [
    "Ana",
    "Augusto",
    "Caroline",
    "Célia",
    "Danielle"    
  ],
  [
    "Brenda",
    "Guilherme",
    "Jessica",
    "Julio",
    "Pedro"
  ]
]
```

I'm struggling to get that into an datatable where the first 3 rows come from the array of objects and the other 3 to be an dropdown with the list of the values of the other arrays. Here's what I have on the columns of the datatable:

```
    columns: [
        { data: "codigo" },
        { data: "razao" },
        { data: "registro"},
        { data: 1,
          className: "text-center",
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){
            var retorno = '<select><option>'+data+'</option></select>'
            return retorno;
          }
        },
        { data: 2,
          className: "text-center",
          render: function(data, type, row, meta){
            var retorno = '<select><option>'+data+'</option></select>'
            return retorno;
          }
        },
        { data: 3,
          className: "text-center",
          render: function(data, type, row, meta){
            var retorno = '<select><option>'+data+'</option></select>'
            return retorno;
          }
        }
    ],
```

What is missing, it seems I'm not calling the values of the object array properly.

[This is what I get rendered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HDHR.png)